# Janela do Logcat no Webstorm 10

Tags: apache-cordova, mobile

tenho até vergonha de perguntar isso, mas vamos lá:

Uso o WebStorm 10 para desenvolver meus aplicativos utilizando o Cordova e faz meses que procuro por uma funcionalidade mínima e simplesmente não consigo encontrar: A Janela do Logcat!

Uso a janela do Eclipse e acho simplesmente excelente, só que é chato ficar com 2 ferramentas abertas.

Eu simplesmente acho absurdo que o Webstorm não tenha isso!

Bem, procurando na Web eu encontro vários textos no site da Jetbrains, mas simplesmente nada útil! Alguns plugins tem dependências que simplesmente não existem e não consigo fazer algo simples funcionar.

Então eu gostaria de saber: Algum de vocês sabe como eu habilito o Logcat no WebStorm 10?

Comment: Sei que não é a resposta para a sua pergunta, mas você sabe que o Logcat é uma ferramenta de linha de comando que não depende de IDEs, certo? Você pode deixar a janela do logcat aberta ao mesmo tempo que a sua IDE. Não é ideal, mas funciona.

Comment: Sim, eu sei. Gosto de usar no eclipse pq o logcat é extremamente verboso. Com o eclipse eu consigo acompanha-lo de forma mais simples. Isso que quero saber usar no webstorm.

Comment: Entendo. Boa sorte na pesquisa e não esqueça de postar a resposta aqui caso descubra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de muita pesquisa acabei encontrando uma solução alternativa: O próprio sdk oferece uma GUI chamada Monitor, localizada em %android_sdk_path%\tools\monitor.exe.

Ele oferece uma visão satisfatória para mim e certamente é bem melhor que ficar com o eclipse e o webstorm abertos.

Apenas por curiosidade o eclipse apresenta uma janela com a mesma ferramenta, então é como se eu executasse somente a aba do eclipse que me interessa.

Problema resolvido!